# SQL data insert to table error

Tags: php, sql, database, image, upload

I am trying to insert copy image to folder and save image path to SQL table. I have used the following code to store image in folder and path to database. When I run code image is copied but path of image is not stored in database.

```
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $target_path)) {
    $query_upload="INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES('".$target_path."','".date("Y-m-d")."')";
    mysql_query($query_upload) or die("error in $query_upload == ----> ".mysql_error());
```

when I run it I get the following error

```
error in INSERT into 'images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('images/21-07-2014-1405927802.png','2014-07-21') == ----> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''images_tbl' ('images_path','submission_date') VALUES ('images/21-07-2014-14' at line 1
```

Comment: Try to remove simple quotes `'` on your table and field names.

Answer (score 0):

Your table name should not have single quotes around it, i.e. it should be:

```
INSERT INTO images_tbl ...
```

or

```
INSERT INTO `images_tbl` ... (note this uses backticks rather than single quotes)
```